# calculate date from String in scala

Tags: java, scala, date, datetime, java-8

Hello I want to convert these kinds of Strings into Date using the LocalDateTime JAVA API . 
Below is the input Strings :  "1672017" that I want to convert to the corresponding date based on the date whose number is 167 in the year 2017.

Any idea how to do this please

Comment: What do dates within the first 99 days of the year look like? `0062017` and `0882017`? Or `62017` and `882017`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`D` represents day of year, so you can use

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DDDyyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("1672017", format);
```